# Formatting Excel Document in Qt

Tags: excel, activex, qt4

I am using Qt 4.5 and Windows XP. I need to create an Microsoft Excel Document that has data (some labels and values) from the Qt application. I need to format those data with some fonts,bold,italics,color, background color etc., Besides ordinary data, there will be Picture files (JPG) also. I need to add those into the Excel. I know retrieving values from Excel using `QAxWidget`, `QAxObject`. But I don't have a clue about the formatting options that can be applied to cells through Qt and adding images as well?? Any help regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options:

1. **Use a cross platform library**

   - xlslib is one such library
2. **Use the [Excel Object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx) directly** If your program will run on a
   machine that has office installed
   you can use COM or ActiveX to tie into the
   Excel object model to create the
   workbooks. Excel has a rich and
   complete object that will let you do
   most operations.
3. **Write to an intermediate database** Write the QT
   data to some type of database and
   pull the data using Excel. This
   route requires in depth Excel
   knowledge and a database.
4. **Write out an XML format that Excel can understand**

   - Excel 2003 can understand
     SpreadsheetML. Simple formatting
     should be straight forward to construct an XML
     document for. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226687(office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226687%28office.11%29.aspx)
   - Excel 2007 can
     understand OpenXML. I have not worked
     with it, but I understand it is more
     complicated (i.e. more feature rich) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx